# NavMesh not including all the surfaces

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I have a level made with pro builders and at that level there is an agent who attacks the player. The problem is that when i baked the navMeshSurface i did not include all the walkable surfaces. See the image below :-
[image]

I am now really frustrated with how to solve the problem, i tried nearly everything. I tried changing the layers and also tried placing other game objects over the area which are not baked. But, it did not work.
Please tell how can i include all the surfaces in the navMeshSurface.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have selected all the blocks, because if you didn't it will only bake the ones that are selected.